# Return the line and column of the value imeadtly higher than a given one

Tags: excel

I want to get the value of a - column G - and b - line 2- in two different cells that correspond to the number imeadtly higher than the one given in one cell, ex:  E7.

Basically i want to look for the value, imeadtly higher to a given one, in a matrix and i'm looking for the formula that gives me the correspondent value of the line and the column.

prntscr.com/7nza32

If the given value is 121 i want  the answer for a to be 125 and for b to be 100

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing as the cell references you are providing don't match the table example.  For example there is no column `G` and the highlighted cell on the table you don't reference at all. Could you clarify further using your example a little closer. Cheers.

Comment: You are absolutely right.
Try this one:
http://prntscr.com/7nza32

Answer (score 1):

Please consider the following solution. Note that when Curly brackets are used (`{` and `}`) this represents that formula is inputted as array formula using `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`.

To find the smallest value that is higher than `E7`:

```
F7 {=MIN(IF(E7<H3:K10,H3:K10,""))}
```

To find value in A:

```
F8 {=SUM(IF(H3:K10=F7,G3:G10,""))}
```

To find value in B:

```
F9 {=SUM(IF(H3:K10=F7,H2:K2,""))}
```

Regards,

Comment: Thank you, its a great day when a solution presents itself in such a simple form. A note to consider, that I forgot to mention, is that there is an assumption that values in your table are all unique. If they weren't then you would likely get the sum of both values for A and both values for B. Cheers